# Pagination in Spring data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, pagination, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How do I convert a list  to Page Object using Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA with One based index (by default the Page object is created with zero based Index).

I tried with

```
  @Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
           PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new 
           PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
           resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
           argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
           super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
   }
}
```

but it does not take effect . I'm creating the page object as

```
  `new PageImpl<Address>(address, pageable, totalCount);`
```